# In Outlook 2007 is it possible to whitelist a domain plus all possible subdomains?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, spam-prevention, subdomain, email-filter

I frequently receive mail from a domain which uses a newly-generated subdomain tree in the From address each time, e.g.

```
blah@foo1.bar2.example.com

glarg@foo3.bar4.example.com
```

The subdomain names can't be predicted and I'm not sure whether the subdomain count is always two, but that may be the case.  I want to whitelist anything coming in from `example.com` regardless of subdomain because Outlook generates lots of junk email false positives with these particular emails.  I am forever having to rescue the messages from the Junk E-Mail folder, which is doubly annoying because after I do that Outlook just dumps the email into my inbox without applying my rules which would normally file them into a specific folder.

I have tried adding `example.com` to the safe senders list, but Outlook modifies this to `@example.com` so any subdomains are specifically excluded.

I have also tried adding `@*.example.com` and `@*.*.example.com` but these don't work either.  I assume we're not allowed to use wildcards in the safe senders list?

Anyone know of any other options or a way to trick Outlook into whitelisting the entire domain?

Comment: have you tried just (asterisk).example.com instead of (asterisk).(asterisk).example.com? excuse the format, this page wont let me use asterisk character properly for some reason

Comment: Yes I've tried that.  Will update the question to make it clearer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, wildcards in the safe senders list are not supported.

If the domains follow a specific pattern and there aren't unlimited variations, you could try  generating a text file of all possible domains and then [importing it into the safe senders list](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/outlook-help/import-e-mail-addresses-into-your-junk-e-mail-filter-lists-HP001230035.aspx).

Eg;

```
@foo1.bar1.example.com
@foo2.bar1.example.com
@foo3.bar1.example.com
@foo4.bar1.example.com
...
@foo1.bar2.example.com
@foo2.bar2.example.com
@foo3.bar2.example.com
@foo4.bar2.example.com
...
```

This may be more trouble than it's worth though!

Comment: Thanks Garrulinae.  Sadly the numbers don't seem to follow any obvious pattern.  I had assumed that, by consistently adding each new domain to the safe list as the emails came in, I would eventually start to see fewer junk mail hits, but that doesn't seem to be the case :( ... Such a pity the Outlook client doesn't have more flexible junk mail filtering controls.